# Azure web role suddenly not starting

Tags: azure, iis, .net-4.5, azure-web-roles

I have Web Application that was hosted in azure web role the application worked well suddenly the application stopped working it won't started but in cloud service it show running status.

I login azure web role in remote desktop and check it in event viewer it shows the following error message, I don't know why it will come?? Anybody knows please let me know.

**Error message 1: IISW3SVC-WP**

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP
Date:          7/6/2016 11:34:58 AM
Event ID:      2297
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      RD00155DF89FB1
Description:
The worker process for application pool '731c10db-e31a-490a-b2ba-7250e7ff6c46' encountered an error 'Configuration file is not well-formed XML
' trying to read global module configuration data from file '\\?\D:\inetpub\temp\apppools\731c10db-e31a-490a-b2ba-7250e7ff6c46\731c10db-e31a-490a-b2ba-7250e7ff6c46.config', line number '3'.  Worker process startup aborted.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP" Guid="{670080D9-742A-4187-8D16-41143D1290BD}" EventSourceName="W3SVC-WP" />
<EventID Qualifiers="49152">2297</EventID>
<Version>0</Version>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Opcode>0</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-06T11:34:58.000000000Z" />
<EventRecordID>517</EventRecordID>
<Correlation />
<Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer>RD00155DF89FB1</Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="ApplicationPool">731c10db-e31a-490a-b2ba-7250e7ff6c46</Data>
<Data Name="ConfigException">Configuration file is not well-formed XML
</Data>
<Data Name="FileName">\\?\D:\inetpub\temp\apppools\731c10db-e31a-490a-b2ba-    7250e7ff6c46\731c10db-e31a-490a-b2ba-7250e7ff6c46.config</Data>
<Data Name="LineNumber">3</Data>
<Binary>0D000000</Binary>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

**Error message 2: .Net Runtime**

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          7/6/2016 11:36:03 AM
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      RD00155DF89FB1
Description:
Application: IISConfigurator.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Stack:    
 at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.AppHostWritableAdminManager.GetAdminSection(String bstrSectionName, String bstrSectionPath)
 at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration.GetSectionInternal(ConfigurationSection section, String sectionPath, String locationPath)
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.ConfigureAnonymousAuthentication(String configPath)
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(Boolean setupRewrite, String configPath)
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(Boolean, System.String)
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.IISConfigurator.Initialize()
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.WCFServiceHost.Open()
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.StartForgroundProcess()
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.DoActions(System.String[])
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.Main(System.String[])

 Event Xml:
 <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
 <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
 <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID>
 <Level>2</Level>
 <Task>0</Task>
 <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
 <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-06T11:36:03.000000000Z" />
 <EventRecordID>543</EventRecordID>
 <Channel>Application</Channel>
 <Computer>RD00155DF89FB1</Computer>
 <Security />
 </System>
 <EventData>
 <Data>Application: IISConfigurator.exe
  Framework Version: v4.0.30319
  Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
  Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  Stack:
  at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.AppHostWritableAdminManager.GetAdminSection(String bstrSectionName, String bstrSectionPath)
  at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration.GetSectionInternal(ConfigurationSection section, String sectionPath, String locationPath)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.ConfigureAnonymousAuthentication(String configPath)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(Boolean setupRewrite, String configPath)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(Boolean, System.String)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.IISConfigurator.Initialize()
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.WCFServiceHost.Open()
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.StartForgroundProcess()
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.DoActions(System.String[])
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.Program.Main(System.String[])
 </Data>
 </EventData>
 </Event>
```

**Error message 3: Application Error**

```
 Log Name:      Application
 Source:        Application Error
 Date:          7/6/2016 11:36:03 AM
 Event ID:      1000
 Task Category: (100)
 Level:         Error
 Keywords:      Classic
 User:          N/A
 Computer:      RD00155DF89FB1
 Description:
 Faulting application name: IISConfigurator.exe, version: 2.7.1198.742, time stamp: 0x5637c82c
 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.17637, time stamp: 0x56980227
 Exception code: 0xe0434352
 Fault offset: 0x000000000004b418
 Faulting process id: 0x1c04
 Faulting application start time: 0x01d1d77a90ba3489
 Faulting application path: E:\base\x64\IISConfigurator.exe
 Faulting module path: D:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
 Report Id: d17be5a6-436d-11e6-93fb-00155df89fb1
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID: 
 Event Xml:
 <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
 <Provider Name="Application Error" />
 <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
 <Level>2</Level>
 <Task>100</Task>
 <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
 <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-06T11:36:03.000000000Z" />
 <EventRecordID>544</EventRecordID>
 <Channel>Application</Channel>
 <Computer>RD00155DF89FB1</Computer>
 <Security />
 </System>
 <EventData>
 <Data>IISConfigurator.exe</Data>
 <Data>2.7.1198.742</Data>
 <Data>5637c82c</Data>
 <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
 <Data>6.2.9200.17637</Data>
 <Data>56980227</Data>
 <Data>e0434352</Data>
 <Data>000000000004b418</Data>
 <Data>1c04</Data>
 <Data>01d1d77a90ba3489</Data>
 <Data>E:\base\x64\IISConfigurator.exe</Data>
 <Data>D:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
 <Data>d17be5a6-436d-11e6-93fb-00155df89fb1</Data>
 <Data>
 </Data>
 <Data>
 </Data>
 </EventData>
 </Event>
```

I have done external operation in that web role, I don't know whether it will throw the issue,
My web role application will call this one command file in service definition file when application start that file will run, this is the given code we start the command file in service definition file,

```
 <Startup>
 <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" />
 </Startup>
```

When that command file will run it checks and reset the IIS every 4 days.

This is the commands executed in command file,

```
echo off
REM *** Prevent the IIS app pools from shutting down due to being idle.
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00

REM *** Prevent IIS app pool recycles from recycling on the default schedule of 1740 minutes (29 hours).
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.recycling.periodicRestart.time:96:00:00


exit /b 0
```